# Is there a good recent review on the treatment options for COVID19?

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2, treatment-options

I am looking for a summary/review of all the treatment options that have been studied for COVID19?

The British medical journal is updating a tremendously helpful ressource (https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.m2980) and I have found one other review article by Tarighi et al (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejphar.2021.173890).

Are there any other good sources?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far?